# How to set a specific property on a private object

Tags: javascript, object

I want to be able to set a property on a **private** object by giving the not notation path to the value. The difficulty is that this object is within closure so I can't access it directly to set the value the normal way (eg. `dot.notation.path = 'new value'`). This seems weird but I can't think of the obvious way.

**Example:**

```
// setter function   
function set(path, change){
    var privateObject = {
      a: 'a',
      b: 'b',
      c: {
          d: 'd',
          e: 'e'
      }
    }

    privateObject[path] = change;
    return privateObject;
}

// execution
var result = set('c.d', 'new value'); 

// desired result
//{
//  a: "a"
//  b: "b"
//  c: {
//    d: "new value",
//    e: 'e'
//  }
//}

// actual result
//{
//  a: "a"
//  b: "b"
//  c: {
//    d: 'd',
//    e: 'e'
//  }
//  c.d: "new value"
//}
```

**Working Example:**

[Failing JSFiddle Example >>](http://jsfiddle.net/spwDp/4/)

**[Update] Alternative Example:**

[Working JSFiddle Example >>](http://jsfiddle.net/spwDp/10/)

Answer (score 5):

You're really close, but the bracket notation won't handle dots for you (it can't — the dots are perfectly valid characters for property names). You have to do that yourself:

```
function set(path, change){
  var privateObject = {
        a: 'a',
        b: 'b',
        c: {
            d: 'd',
            e: 'e'
        }
      },
      index,
      parts,
      obj;

  parts = path.split(".");
  obj = privateObject;
  if (parts.length) {
    index = 0;
    while (index < parts.length - 1) {
      obj = obj[parts[index++]];
    }
    obj[parts[index]] = change;
  }
  return privateObject;
}
```

[Live demo](http://jsbin.com/atekag)

I dashed that off, it's not hyper-efficient on older engines and I didn't bother to explore failure modes, but you get the idea: Split the path you're giving on the dot, then use each component part of the page.

Comment: Wow cool you understood what I meant! Is this the easiest way to set a specific value on a private object?

Comment: @pagewil: Short of supplying the path to it as individual strings, it's pretty simple. :-)

Comment: @pagewil: If your goal is to make the object public, but to prevent others from swapping in a completely different object for it, that seems fine. Of course, the same people could just as easily swap in different `setter` and `logger` functions to get the same result. But perhaps it raises the bar. :-) What I'd do instead of all of this is define the mutators you want to define, not a blanket "here it is, do what you want" -- or make the object a normal property.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't have anything to do with private objects or closures, and a lot do with the fact that

```
someObject['c.d']
```

is not equivalent to

```
someObject['c']['d']
```

or

```
someObject.c.d
```

You can make some construct that splits your `path` string by the . separator and applies the indexing operator iteratively to achieve the desired effect.

However, the whole exercise seems kind of pointless. If you're performing arbitrary changes to a private object from outside its scope, why not just add a mechanism for getting the private object and mutate it directly?

Comment: While true, this doesn't really answer the question. It just says what he's doing won't work -- which he already knows, since it fails. :-)

Comment: @pagewil - Yes, that looks better :-)